# How to get a correlation matrix from two pair columns in R and SAS ? The diagonal is zero

Tags: r, sas

I have a data frame looks like following; I used R to transfer two columns to a matrix, but R cannot give me the matrix. (My expected matrix is about 700*700.) R stoped and show `Reached total allocation of 12213Mb: see help(memory.size)`

I want to do the same thing in SAS. How can we do that? Or do I need different code to finish this in R?

```
ID_r ID_c SCORE
A1   A2   0.2
A1   A3   0.2
A1   A4   0.3
A1   A5   0.2
A1   A6   0.2
A2   A3   0.6
A2   A4   0.2
A2   A5   0.2
A2   A6   0.2
A3   A4   0.2
A3   A5   0.2
A3   A6   0.2
A4   A5   0.2
A4   A6   0.9
A5   A6   0.2

    ID_r<-c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A4','A4','A5')
    ID_c<-c('A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A3','A4','A5','A6','A4','A5','A6','A5','A6','A6')
    SCORE<-c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.9,0.2)

library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df$ID_r <- as.character(df$ID_r)
df$ID_c <- as.character(df$ID_c)
ID <- unique(c(df$ID_r, df$ID_c))
diagDf <- data.frame(ID_r = ID, ID_c = ID, SCORE = "0.0")
newDf <- rbind(df, diagDf) %>% arrange(ID_r, ID_c)

resultDf <- spread(newDf, ID_r, SCORE, fill = ".")
names(resultDf)[1] <- ""
resultDf
```

The sample SAS data is as following.

```
data score_data;
infile datalines;
input ID_r $ ID_c $ SCORE;
return;
datalines;

    A1   A2   0.2
    A1   A3   0.2
    A1   A4   0.3
    A1   A5   0.2
    A1   A6   0.2
    A2   A3   0.6
    A2   A4   0.2
    A2   A5   0.2
    A2   A6   0.2
    A3   A4   0.2
    A3   A5   0.2
    A3   A6   0.2
    A4   A5   0.2
    A4   A6   0.9
    A5   A6   0.2
;
run;

proc print data=score_data ;
run;
```

And I want to use the two columns data to generate a matrix like the following (diaginal is zero).

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6
A1 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.2
A2 0.2 0.0 0.6 0.2 0.2 0.2 
A3 0.2 0.6 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.2
A4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.2 0.9
A5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.0 0.2
A6 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.9 0.2 0.0
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `R` solution:

```
library(plyr)
ID_r = c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A4','A4','A5')
ID_c = c('A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A3','A4','A5','A6','A4','A5','A6','A5','A6','A6')
SCORE = c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.9,0.2)
df1 = data.frame(ID_r, ID_c, SCORE)
df2 = data.frame(ID_c, ID_r, SCORE)
names(df2) = c("ID_r","ID_c","SCORE")
df = rbind(df1,df2)
ID <- unique(c(ID_r, ID_c))

df1 = expand.grid(ID,ID)
names(df1) = c("ID_r","ID_c")
d = join(df1, df, by = c("ID_r","ID_c"))
d$SCORE[is.na(d$SCORE)] <- 0

a = matrix(0, nrow = length(ID), ncol = length(ID))
rownames(a) <- ID
colnames(a) <- ID
a

b = as.matrix(d)
b

a[b[,1:2]] <- b[,3]
a
```

Comment: `join` needs the `plyr` package.

Comment: `join` by default uses the type `left`. Which is what you need in this problem. What error you are getting?

Comment: Use the edited answer. You need `library(plyr)`. You can also go to the "packages" tab in RStudio and select the checkbox against `plyr`.

Comment: Can you give more details? You original problem did not have anything with 1-12 in rows/cols

Comment: Thank you!!!  After change the id_r from A1 to 1, it perfectly generate the csv matrix!!! Thank you so so so much!!! This is so amazing.

Answer (score 1):

`PROC TRANSPOSE` is your friend here.

```
proc transpose data=score_data out=score_matrix;
  by id_r; 
  id id_c; *this makes variable names;
  var score;
run;
```

This will give you the upper diagonal.  A second `proc transpose` could give you the lower diagonal (swapping `id_r` and `id_c` I imagine), or you could do it in the dataset.  You'd still have to create the six 0.0 rows in the dataset, but that shouldn't be particularly difficult.

An example of doing this:

```
data pre_transpose;
  set score_data end=eof;
  by id_r id_c;
  output;

  *Swap R and C;
  _idtemp = id_r;
  id_r=id_c;
  id_c=_idtemp;
  output;

  *If EOF, then need that last 0,0 combo which never gets an R;
   if eof then do;
    id_c = id_r;
    score=0;
    output;
    id_c = _idtemp;
  end;

  *If first line of a new ID, then need the R=C row;
  if first.id_r then do;
    id_r=id_c;
    score=0;
    output;
  end;

run;

proc sort data=pre_transpose;
  by id_r id_c;
run;
proc transpose data=pre_transpose out=score_matrix;
  by id_r; 
  id id_c; *this makes variable names;
  var score;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works perfectly!!!! Thank you so much. I learn a lot SAS coding from your answers.